# Another possibilities than wait?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am trying to automate a website where the testing environment is reduced and the page loads nearly two minutes(120000).
I don't want to use cy.wait(120000) or cy.pause() command.
Could anyone help by giving more suggestions to solve the issue even the testing environment gets slower than this.
I have tried should,intercept,etc..,Other than the normal ones can someone suggest me some ideas.It wil be more helpful if you post your answers with commands.

Comment: Maybe a solution would be to use async...await statements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cy.wait` is not a good practice in most situations because it just hangs your program to wait till the end of the timeout.

I think you're looking for a solution to wait for an element appears in HTML, so I'd suggest you to check [this part](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress#Example-2-Additional-Assertions) of the document

In your case, it should be like below

```
cy.get('.selector', { timeout: 120000 }).should('be.visible')
```

Even though the timeout is longer but whenever your `.selector` appears on the HTML, it will pass.

Note that, the default `timeout` is only 4 seconds, so if you want to have more `timeout`, you can modify it to longer (like 2 mins for your case).

Why do we need to have `timeout`? Well, basically, we don't want the program hangs forever, so that's why we need to have timeout.

Comment: Thank you for your response.I got the output.But is there anyother way to get the element's response without using timeout also.@https://stackoverflow.com/users/9201587/nick-vu

Comment: I also mentioned this part `Why do we need to have timeout? Well, basically, we don't want the program hangs forever, so that's why we need to have timeout.` Cypress requires us to have a certain timeout to make the program avoid hanging forever (even though you don't pass the timeout, it will be set 4 seconds as default). With my above example, you can set the timeout like 1 day or 1 week, and as soon as you get the expected element, `cy.get` will pass and continue other next steps that is different from `cy.wait` @razeem